# How to reload or update a viewController's view once a file is saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsxmlparser, nsxmlparserdelegate

Is it possible to reload/update a viewController's view once a file gets saved in the documents folder? 
If yes, kindly suggest how to accomplish this.

I'm trying to save a file in *AppDelegate*, but as it involves XML parsing, it is saved only when a view gets loaded. This is the view that is supposed to show the contents of the file. But as it gets loaded before the file is saved, the view doesn't display anything.

This query is related to my question at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435324/data-wont-load-after-xml-parsing)

Shall I share the code here again?

Comment: what is exactly has to be overloaded?

Comment: I'm saving a file in AppDelegate and then a viewController is loaded, I'm checking if the file is present, if _YES_ load the file's contents into the view.
Else display a message that there is nothing to display. But when I debug the app, I discovered that my method in AppDelegate is creating and saving the file after the view has been loaded and displayed, and the view displays a _nothing to show message_ . 
Hope I'm able to explain my problem.

I'm not overloading anything.

Comment: *load the file's contents into the view* <- do you mean load its content into the labels, textView etc.?

Comment: yes. I'm trying to do this.But I'm only loading specific content. As the file has been XML parsed, it contains `NSDictionary` objects and I'm only loading the  values of certain `keys` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can guide you through the process. What you need to implement is:

1. When your file gets written to the storage, you can post a `Notification` through `NotificationCenter`. (Additionally you can check for the existence of the file immediately before posting the `Notification`).
2. Add an `observer` for listening to that `Notification` through `NotificationCenter` in your `ViewController` (maybe inside `viewDidLoad()`).
3. When you add the `observer` you need to specify a `selector`(method) which will be called when the notification occurs. So add a method and provide it as the `selector` for addObserver.
4. Do your required operations in that method and at the last of the method mark your `view` dirty. It is usually done with `self.view.setNeedsDisplay()`. This will do the reloading/updating part.

> **EDIT**: added some code example

Here I'm posting relevant code. Focus on the comments inside the code.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    postNotificationAfterFileSave()
    return true
}

func postNotificationAfterFileSave() {
    // do your job with your custom class's method for saving
    // you should get a filepath back
    CustomXMLParser().parseAndSave { (filePath) in
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
            // if the file exists, post Notification
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FileWrittenCompletion"), object: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // add an observer for your Notification and specify a selector that will be called when Notification is got
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateUI), name: Notification.Name("FileWrittenCompletion"), object: nil)
    myLabel.text = "File is being saved"
}

@objc func updateUI() {
    // this method will be called when Notification happens
    // change your UI objects according to your needs
    myLabel.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8078431487, green: 0.02745098062, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1)
    myLabel.text = "File is saved successfully"
    // Finally mark your view `dirty` that will do the reloading task of the UI
    self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

**CustomXMLParser.swift**

```
func parseAndSave(completion: @escaping (String)-> Void ) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 10
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
        let string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
        // get the document directory
        let fileURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("myFile").appendingPathExtension("txt")

        do {
            // write to filepath
            try string.write(to: fileURL!, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // return the filePath through completion block
                completion((fileURL?.path)!)
            }

        } catch {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nayem , have already tried it. Didn't work. I appreciate  your help.

Comment: Give some time, I'm trying to implement a demo for this.

Comment: Sure. I'll wait.

Comment: @Prashant, Hey I've done the demo but in `Swift`. Will it be a problem? And should I post only the relevant code here or should I upload the whole project somewhere else?

Comment: Sure, no problem you could post it here. Or upload it on some file hosting website and post a link, whatever you feel like.

Comment: I too have tried this approach, but as I'm using background tasks, for completing XML parsing, via a custom class meant for parsing XML. It would be wrong to include a code for posting notification in that class. I appreciate your effforts.

Comment: No you don't have to include the code for posting `Notification` in that class. You just have to get the main queue where you have called your custom class's method (I believe you mentioned your AppDelegate) . And inside the main queue, you just post the `Notification`.

Comment: Tried it earlier, will try again but with a slight modification. Thanks @nayem

Comment: Thanks for all the help @nayem  , but looks like this approach too isn't working for me, will keep tweaking my code and when I do get it right, will post it here.

Comment: Okay. Do your parsing/saving method of your `CustomXMLParser` class have a completion block? Or do you have the permission to modify your `CustomXMLParser` class?

Comment: a completion block.

Comment: Great. Can you modify the `completion block` to be executed on `Main Queue`? I've done another demo.

Comment: @Prashant You can find the source code [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzxb70Gwq7HWVEZ1cTZNVFNsZGc) and I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @nayem . I'll check.

Comment: Hey, changed my approach altogether, that worked. Thanks for your help @nayem

Comment: @Prashant If the approach was right and if that helped you sorting the problem out, you should mark this as accepted answer. That will help others to find out similar type issues.

Comment: Like I said, your approach and logic is definitely right. But I had to alter my entire approach to make code reusable, as my project is pretty big. But I'll accept your answer as this might help others